# Broken rendered output in suggested edits review queue

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-queues, suggested-edits

[The review for this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22600065) has broken rendered output on the left:

[image: The code in the original post appears as empty code blocks.]

But [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49836288/9609843) looks good outside of review:

[image: The code is visible as inline code sections, not blocks, and properly indented in the ordered list.]

Comment: I'm able to verify on Chrome for Android and Firefox for Windows 10, looks like a good bug.

Comment: And I tested it on Ubuntu16.04 with Opera and Firefox.

Comment: I think you mean "broken rendering"; the view you are showing is not the markdown view. But it's not broken; the original use GitHub flavor code demarcation, with the code immediately following the tickmarks, causing an empty code block to appear.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes, you are right, edited question accordingly.

Comment: <gulp>triple backticks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is by design and an artifact of a transition we went through to add support for ```` ``` ```` blocks.

Earlier this year we added support for these blocks, making

````
1. ```javascript
2. var x = 1;
3. ```
````

render as

```
var x = 1;
```

Unfortunately, we already supported ```` ``` ```` for inline code.  I'm guessing it was so you could do `` backticks ` in code `` but it also supported line breaks while producing inline code.

So originally, that post had backticks with line breaks that functioned as inline code, but upon edit and re-rendering, those became code blocks and markdown treated the first line as a type hint erasing their content.

**But what's happening in the preview?**

The preview is using our new markdown renderer to show both the before and after HTML, so the HTML is rendering poorly because it was written for a different renderer.  We just don't have things set up to continue rendering old revisions with the old renderer and new revisions with the new renderer and are accepting that as a cost of the transition.  This issue only comes up at most once per post and there is supposed to be tooling in place to aid editors crossing that bridge.

Comment: Something is really "off" here. Look at this question for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56432801/multi-threading-issue ... the OP is using 3 backticks all over his questions. I am wondering: is that because he really *typed* them, or is some of the markup buttons inserting those?!